Match debugpy attach from VSCode in Pycharm
I have a docker container running locally and I want to debug the code that is running in the container. Right now i was shown a method to do that in VSCode which runs the below launch.json to attach to the process and it works.
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "16: Agora",
      "type": "debugpy",
      "request": "attach",
      "debugServer": 8888,
      "pathMappings": [
        {
          "localRoot": "/path/to/folder/Odoo-Dev/syscoon/agora/internal_addons",
          "remoteRoot": "/mnt/odoo/internal_addons"
        },
        {
          "localRoot": "/path/to/folder/Odoo-Dev/syscoon/agora/external_addons",
          "remoteRoot": "/mnt/odoo/external_addons"
        },
        {
          "localRoot": "/path/to/folder/Odoo-Dev/syscoon/agora/",
          "remoteRoot": "/mnt/odoo/syscoon_addons"
        },
        {
          "localRoot": "/path/to/folder/Odoo-Dev/odoo-sync/addons",
          "remoteRoot": "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons"
        },
        {
          "localRoot": "/path/to/folder/Odoo-Dev/enterprise",
          "remoteRoot": "/mnt/odoo-enterprise"
        }
      ],
      "logToFile": true,
      "justMyCode": false
    }
  ]
}

My issue is that my preferred IDE is pycharm and using VSCode is really inefficient as i am used to pycharm.
Any idea how i can configure pycharm to do the same?
I am not too familiar with the docker setup as it is a company thing so i do not have alot of access to change things there.
Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.
I have tried the below configuration but i keep getting address is already in use probably because the docker container running will cause that.
debugger configuration
It runs with the below option, but then i do not use docker compose up to run it and it is rather slow when using the below method, it also does not use the .env from docker
python run configured using remote python interpreter
